# Does Spring Attack work with the Skirmisher ability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, rogue, archetype

The Scout archetype for the Rogue grants the *skirmisher* ability at 8th level:

> At 8th level, whenever a scout moves more than 10 feet in a round and
>   makes an attack action, the attack deals sneak attack damage as if the
>   target was flat-footed. If the scout makes more than one attack this
>   turn, this ability only applies to the first attack. Foes with uncanny
>   dodge are immune to this ability.

Does this work if I'm using the *spring attack* feat, which in Pathfinder is a special full round action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Skirmisher explicitly requires an attack action, and Spring Attack cannot be used in conjunction with anything that requires an attack action.

An [Editor's Note](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/spring-attack-combat---final) on D20PFSRD says :

> **Can Vital Strike be used with Spring Attack? Can Vital Strike be used
>   on a charge?**
>
> No. Vital Strike can only be used as part of an attack action, which
>   is a specific kind of standard action. **Spring Attack is a special kind
>   of full-round action that includes the ability to make one melee
>   attack, not one attack action.** Charging uses similar language and can
>   also not be used in combination with Vital Strike.

Then Skirmisher cannot be used in conjunction with Spring Attack.